# MongoDB Atlas connection issue with Django

Tags: python, django, mongodb, pymongo, djongo

I am trying to connect my Django application with the Atlas MongoDB cloud database using Djongo. The setting file database section is,

```
DATABASES = {
       'default': {
           'ENGINE': 'djongo',
           'NAME': 'mydb',
           'HOST': 'mongodb+srv://user:' + urllib.parse.quote_plus('password') + '@xx-xxxxx.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
           'USER': 'user',
           'PASSWORD': 'password',
       }
   }
```

But after running `python manage.py migrate`, it is throwing the following error,

```
File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 87, in handle
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 212, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 73, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 56, in has_table
    return self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor())
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\introspection.py", line 48, in table_names
    return get_names(cursor)
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\introspection.py", line 43, in get_names
    return sorted(ti.name for ti in self.get_table_list(cursor)
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\djongo\introspection.py", line 47, in get_table_list
    for c in cursor.db_conn.list_collection_names()
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pymongo\database.py", line 856, in list_collection_names
    for result in self.list_collections(session=session, **kwargs)]
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pymongo\database.py", line 818, in list_collections
    return self.__client._retryable_read(
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1453, in _retryable_read
    server = self._select_server(
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1253, in _select_server
    server = topology.select_server(server_selector)
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 233, in select_server
    return random.choice(self.select_servers(selector,
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 192, in select_servers
    server_descriptions = self._select_servers_loop(
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 208, in _select_servers_loop
    raise ServerSelectionTimeoutError(
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

If you look at the last line it says that pymongo is trying to connect `localhost:27017`. But the host is already mentioned. As there is no localhost so it is getting the connection failure.

Now, I opened the `mongo_client.py` inside `C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\pymongo` and found the following snippet of code,

```
class MongoClient(common.BaseObject):
    """
    A client-side representation of a MongoDB cluster.

    Instances can represent either a standalone MongoDB server, a replica
    set, or a sharded cluster. Instances of this class are responsible for
    maintaining up-to-date state of the cluster, and possibly cache
    resources related to this, including background threads for monitoring,
    and connection pools.
    """
    HOST = "localhost"
    PORT = 27017
    # Define order to retrieve options from ClientOptions for __repr__.
    # No host/port; these are retrieved from TopologySettings.
    _constructor_args = ('document_class', 'tz_aware', 'connect')

    def __init__(
            self,
            host=None,
            port=None,
            document_class=dict,
            tz_aware=None,
            connect=None,
            type_registry=None,
            **kwargs):
```

As per the overview the default HOST is never overloaded. Therefore it is always searching for localhost. Now, if I change `localhost` to `'mongodb+srv://user:password@xx-xxxxx.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority'`, the connection works correctly.

**Now, definitely it is not the solution indeed. Can anyone throw some light on it?**

Answer (score 0):

The configuration pattern is changed but not mentioned in the official document,

```
DATABASES = {
       'default': {
           'ENGINE': 'djongo',
           'NAME': 'ezlistmongo',
           'CLIENT': {
              'host': 'mongodb+srv://user:' + urllib.parse.quote_plus('password') + '@xx-xxxxx.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
              'port': 27017,
              'username': 'user',
              'password': 'password',
            }
       }
   }
```

Answer courtesy [Joe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2282634/joe). This works perfectly.